# How to run .exe inside a Universal App in Win 10 in VS 2015?

Tags: exe, win-universal-app

I know that System.Diagnostics.Process is not available in Universal App. How do we start a locally stored .exe from an Universal App running in VS 2015?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run an arbitrary executable directly; you need to use `Windows.System.Launcher` to launch via registered URI scheme or file type.